# Is it possible to use default ZoomControls of Maps v2 to zoomIn/Out a custom amount of ZoomLevel such as 0.5x?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a mapFragment such like this

```
   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        tools:context="com....."/>
```

And I enable the default ZoomControle (the "+" and "-" buttons):

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    ...
}
```

Using these ZoomControls enables the users to zoom in/out for 1 Zoomlevel. Using the ZoomGestures, the users can zoom in/out "continuosly" i.e. values between zoomlevels. Can I change the zoom in/out behaviour for the map's ZoomControls as well for a different amount of ZoomLevel than "1" such as 0.5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. The answer is: yes!
Here is how I changed the behavior of the ZoomControls to having hold+click events and Zooming in/Zooming out while being pressed and updating the UI (the map) meanwhile. This approach also lets me set a MaxZoom and MinZoom Level for the mapFragment easily and with a much better user experience than setting back the ZoomLevel within a OnCameraChangeListener!

Ive set an OnTouchListener onto those "+" and "-" childs from the mapFragment. When finger touches the buttom with "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN", a Thread for zooming in/out the map is started. On "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP", the Thread is interrupted:

```
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    // get the default ZoomControls from the mapFragment:
    View zoomControls = mapFragment.getView().findViewById(0x1);

    for(int i=0;i<((ViewGroup)zoomControls).getChildCount();i++){
        View child=((ViewGroup)zoomControls).getChildAt(i);
        if (i==0) {
            // there is your "+" button, zoom in
            child.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            updateZoom = new ZoomInMapThread();
                            updateZoom.start();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            updateZoom.interrupt();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        if (i==1) {
            // there is your "-" button, zoom out
            child.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            updateZoom = new ZoomOutMapThread();
                            updateZoom.start();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            updateZoom.interrupt();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And somewhere at the end of the Activity class, Ive created the ZoomThreads:

```
private class ZoomOutMapThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        currentZoomLevel = currentZoomLevel - 0.1f;
                        if (currentZoomLevel < minZoom){
                            currentZoomLevel = minZoom;
                        }
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(currentZoomLevel));
                        Log.d("Zoom", "Level:" + currentZoomLevel);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException consumed) {
            consumed.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class ZoomInMapThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                // make the Thread able to update the UserInterace:
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // increase the currentZoomLevel by 0.1:
                        currentZoomLevel = currentZoomLevel + 0.1f;
                        // increase only while we have not reached predefined maxZoom:
                        if (currentZoomLevel > maxZoom){
                            currentZoomLevel = maxZoom;
                            // good moment to disable the "+" button somehow
                        }
                        // update the Camera in GoogleMap mMap from onMapReady():  mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(currentZoomLevel));
                        Log.d("Zoom","Level:"+currentZoomLevel);
                    }
                });
                // repeat every 100ms while finger holds the "+"-Button
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException consumed) {
            consumed.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

dont forget to declare class variables:

```
private float maxZoom = 9.99f;
private float minZoom = 8.2f;
private float currentZoomLevel = 9.1f;
```

and for onMapReady(GoogleMap ..):

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);   // prevent rotation UI
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);       // prevent navigate to UI
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);     // prevent default Zoom Gestures
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);      // show default Zoom Controls (+/-)
```